# Javascript form validation when end time is lesser than start time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I have a html/php code as shown below belonging to the following screenshot in which when there is a **drop-down** and **input-box** where we select **Start Day of Week**, **Start Time**, **End Day of Week** and **End Time**.

When we select same day (both for **Start Day of Week** and **End Day of Week**) of the week which is right now in the screenshot below then **end-time should always be greater than start time**. At this moment, **end time is lesser than start time which is not technically right**. 
[image]

```
<form>
      <div style="text-align:right;margin-right:9px;">
        <button type="submit" onclick="check()">Save</button>
    </div>
    <div class="start-time+end-time" style="display:flex; text-align: center">
        <div class="start-time" style="display:inline-flex;align-items:center;justify-content:center;"> 
            <p>Start Day of Week</p>
            <select id="startDay" name="select_start_day" style="margin-left: 10px;">
                <option value="mon" name="select_start_day" <?php if($data->{"select_start_day"}==mon){echo 'selected';}?>>Monday</option>
                <option value="tue" name="select_start_day" <?php if($data->{"select_start_day"}==tue){echo 'selected';}?>>Tuesday</option>
                <option value="wed" name="select_start_day" <?php if($data->{"select_start_day"}==wed){echo 'selected';}?>>Wednesday</option>
                <option value="thu" name="select_start_day" <?php if($data->{"select_start_day"}==thu){echo 'selected';}?>>Thursday</option>
                <option value="fri" name="select_start_day" <?php if($data->{"select_start_day"}==fri){echo 'selected';}?>>Friday</option>
                <option value="sat" name="select_start_day" <?php if($data->{"select_start_day"}==sat){echo 'selected';}?>>Saturday</option>
                <option value="sun" name="select_start_day" <?php if($data->{"select_start_day"}==sun){echo 'selected';}?>>Sunday</option>         
            </select>
            <p style="margin-left:12px;margin-right:10px;">time(hhmm)&nbsp;</p>
            <input type="text" name="start_time" style="width: 12%;height: 22px;" value="<?php if($data->{"start_time"}<>''){echo $data->{"start_time"};} ?>">
        </div>
        <div class="end-time" style="display:inline-flex;align-items:center;justify-content:center;">
             <p>End Day of Week</p>
             <select id="endDay" name="select_end_day" style="margin-left: 10px;">
                <option value="mon" name="select_end_day" <?php if($data->{"select_end_day"}==mon){echo 'selected';}?>>Monday</option>
                <option value="tue" name="select_end_day" <?php if($data->{"select_end_day"}==tue){echo 'selected';}?>>Tuesday</option>
                <option value="wed" name="select_end_day" <?php if($data->{"select_end_day"}==wed){echo 'selected';}?>>Wednesday</option>
                <option value="thu" name="select_end_day" <?php if($data->{"select_end_day"}==thu){echo 'selected';}?>>Thursday</option>
                <option value="fri" name="select_end_day" <?php if($data->{"select_end_day"}==fri){echo 'selected';}?>>Friday</option>
                <option value="sat" name="select_end_day" <?php if($data->{"select_end_day"}==sat){echo 'selected';}?>>Saturday</option>
                <option value="sun" name="select_end_day" <?php if($data->{"select_end_day"}==sun){echo 'selected';}?>>Sunday</option>         
            </select>
            <p style="margin-left:12px;margin-right:10px;">time(hhmm)&nbsp;</p>
            <input type="text" name="end_time" style="width: 12%;height: 22px;" value="<?php if($data->{"end_time"}<>''){echo $data->{"end_time"};} ?>">
        </div> 
    </div>
</form>
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what **JavaScript** code I need to add when **day of the week is same** then **end time** should always be greater than **start time**. If its not **form should not save** and it 
should throw an **error or warning**.

The above html/php code is inside **form** tag with **save button** at the top.

**This is what I have tried:**

```
function check() {
  if((document.getElementById("startDay").value = "monday") && (document.getElementById("endDay").value = "monday")) {

    }
     else if((document.getElementById("startDay").value = "tuesday") && (document.getElementById("endDay").value = "tuesday")) {

    }   
      else if((document.getElementById("startDay").value = "wednesday") && (document.getElementById("endDay").value = "wednesday")) {

    }   
      else if((document.getElementById("startDay").value = "thursday") && (document.getElementById("endDay").value = "thursday")) {

    }   
      else if((document.getElementById("startDay").value = "friday") && (document.getElementById("endDay").value = "friday")) {

    }   
      else if((document.getElementById("startDay").value = "saturday") && (document.getElementById("endDay").value = "saturday")) {

    }   
      else if((document.getElementById("startDay").value = "sunday") && (document.getElementById("endDay").value = "sunday")) {

    }   
}
```

Comment: There are many different approaches. What have you tried?

Comment: @Moob That is what I have tried. I will update more if I come up with more logic.

Comment: @Moob We have to validate input fields as well. Let me know if its make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the Days fields are in order you can just compare their `selectedIndex`. Add an event listener to capture the form submission, then you can validate the inputs and prevent the submission if there's a problem.

Here's a demo to get you started. I'll leave you to fill in the blanks.

```js
function onReady(fn) {//helper to wait for the DOM
  if (document.readyState != 'loading'){
    fn();
  } else {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fn);
  }
}
function onSubmit(event){//handle the submit event
  var oops = document.getElementById("oops");
  console.clear();

  var startDay = myform.querySelector("select[name='select_start_day']").selectedIndex;
  console.log("startDay",startDay);
  
  var endDay = myform.querySelector("select[name='select_end_day']").selectedIndex;
  console.log("endDay",endDay);
  
  if(startDay>endDay){    
    event.preventDefault();//prevent submission
    oops.innerHTML="Start Day cannot be after End Day!";
    return;
  }
  if(startDay===endDay){ 
    console.log("Same day. Test the times!");
    //todo, check that the startTime is before the endTime
  }
  
  event.preventDefault();//for demo only. remove this line when you're ready to allow submission
  console.log("Would have been submitted if the line above is removed.");
    oops.innerHTML="";
}

//init
onReady(function(){
  console.log("ready");  
  var myform = document.getElementById("myform");
  myform.addEventListener("submit", onSubmit);
});
```

```html
<form id="myform">
<input type="submit" value="submit" /><div id="oops" style="color:red; font-weight:bold;"></div>
<div class="start-time+end-time" style="display:flex; text-align: center">
        <div class="start-time" style="display:inline-flex;align-items:center;justify-content:center;"> 
            <p>Start Day of Week</p>
            <select name="select_start_day" style="margin-left: 10px;">
                <option value="mon">Monday</option>
                <option value="tue">Tuesday</option>
                <option value="wed">Wednesday</option>
                <option value="thu">Thursday</option>
                <option value="fri">Friday</option>
                <option value="sat">Saturday</option>
                <option value="sun">Sunday</option>         
            </select>
            <p style="margin-left:12px;margin-right:10px;">time(hhmm)&nbsp;</p>
            <input type="text" name="start_time" style="width: 12%;height: 22px;" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="end-time" style="display:inline-flex;align-items:center;justify-content:center;">
             <p>End Day of Week</p>
             <select name="select_end_day" style="margin-left: 10px;">
                <option value="mon">Monday</option>
                <option value="tue">Tuesday</option>
                <option value="wed">Wednesday</option>
                <option value="thu">Thursday</option>
                <option value="fri">Friday</option>
                <option value="sat">Saturday</option>
                <option value="sun">Sunday</option>         
            </select>
            <p style="margin-left:12px;margin-right:10px;">time(hhmm)&nbsp;</p>
            <input type="text" name="end_time" style="width: 12%;height: 22px;" value="">
        </div> 
    </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It looks awesome. More than I expected.

Comment: In regards to the 2nd condition, `if(startDay===endDay){ 
   console.log("Same day. Test the times!");
   //todo, check that the startTime is before the endTime
    }`. Is there any way we can put a validation end time should be always greater than start time when days of the week are same ? As it is the main requirement.

Comment: This is what I have tried and it worked https://jsfiddle.net/4ck2z89n/